# Extracting data from feature collection in google earth engine

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine

I have a feature collection: ee.FeatureCollection("RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017") and I would like to get the 'BIOME_NUM' for a set of lat long points I have separately. I've looked all over the internet and haven't found anything that gave me results. I'd appreciate any help!

Someone suggested transforming the feature collection into an image collection, or possibly doing a geometry point in polygon thing, but I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to get specific information from your feature collection:

1st Method is to use to use[.filter(ee.Filter.eq](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-filter-eq)('BIOME_NUM', 'Enter Specific property of BIOME_NUM) with your feature collection

2nd Method is to use [.select](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/classification)(''BIOME_NUM''), (Note: This method will only include your BIOME_NUM data in your feature collection and will remove other data.

Now as far as for your concerned task about information of BIOME_NUM on lat long, draw points ( which you want to assign BIOME_NUM) and then [create a function](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/feature_collection_mapping) that will take your point and assign it BIOME_NUM value from feature collection.

Please share your script so we can help you further in writing function.

Answer (score -1):

```
var ecoregion = ee.FeatureCollection("RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017");
var coordinates = ee.Geometry.Point([-101.1321129322052,41.522537186219715]);

var val = ecoregion.filterBounds(coordinates).first();
print(val.get('BIOME_NAME'));
print(val.get('BIOME_NUM'));
```